# Avoiding the execution upon its installation ldap-auth-config

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, ldap

I am trying to automate (by using a bash script) the installation of packages for LDAP authentication. However, the script is being interrupted by the ldap-auth-config dialog. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the interactive portion with:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

Then run your **apt-get**:

```
apt-get -q -y install libnss-ldapd
```